# Where is 'keyboard layout' under system

Tags: keyboard

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NumLock they say there that there is 'keyboard layout' under system setting. I'm using 14.04 and i can't find it.
Should I download something?

Comment: No dublicate i'd like to get keyboard layout because it had more functions :P

Comment: That particular screen/page looks like it's from 12.04 and is not included in 14.04. See https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-help/keyboard.html

Comment: The "Keyboard Layout" module was replaced with "Text Entry" in Ubuntu 13.10 IIRC. What kind of setting option is it you can't find?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what are you looking for?:

[image: Screencast of keyboard settings]

Comment: That's specific to the GNOME desktop.